# dynamically-generated submit buttons, which one was clicked?

Tags: php, html, submit

Let's assume a page has a bunch of submit buttons that are generated by a PHP loop of some kind. They are named after the loop value, so the result would look something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="0" id="0" value="click me">
<input type="submit" name="1" id="1" value="click me">
```

etc.

Let's say that there could be anywhere between zero and a gazillion of these buttons. Assuming that the form is POST, how would I identify, on the page that loads afterward, which of the buttons had been clicked?

Comment: You can tell which one was clicked because `$_POST['button_name_attribute']` will be set.

Comment: You should provide more information to explain what you are actually trying to achieve. More than likely using an array as the name would be better than just a number.

Comment: That's how I normally check if a button has been clicked, but in this case, I do not know at the time of writing the code what the button names are. For example, let's say there are 22 buttons generated, named numbers 0-21. If the one named "17" was clicked, I would have to have code that went something like `if(isset($_POST["17"]))`. Hypothetically, what if there are 8 million buttons? Would you need to have written 8 million checks for $_POST to see if all those were clicked?

Comment: You'd have to use a loop similar to the one that created the buttons in the submission script. Then use 'break' once you find one set.

Comment: btw, this is entirely theoretical, so I'm not trying to achieve anything specific. I was coding something else and thought of this, and thought I'd find out what you would do in this circumstance.

Comment: Then why don't you do some testing and find out? Could be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, you would be better to use an array in the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100 ; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="submit" name="clicked['.$i.']" value="clicked" />';
}
?>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP you can get the clicked input by doing:

```
echo key($_POST['clicked']); // Prints, for example, 28
```

Comment: Good idea, I've never though of using an array on a submit before.